# magento 2.3.2 - tab not showing in product page because override Magento_PageBuilder

Tags: magento2

magento 2.3.2 tab not showing in product page , because override Magento_PageBuilder. page layout . how to fix this ?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Simply change layout for product in the product edit page (Design section). Choose 3-columns (or 2-columns / 1-column) instead full-width.